# Django / Ubuntu 20 - How change to a previous version of GDAL

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, version, gdal

first of all, thanks for your help.

I'm new to django, and I'm developing a site where you have to enter coordinates in some forms and then they should be editable.

So far, so good, I haven't had any problem creating that, however, as I read, in some of the more recent versions, the order in which GDAL reads the coordinates was changed, so the positions appear inverted when reading data from geospatial databases. In other words, the coordinates are entered right (from PgAdmin they look right) but are read wrong when you load them into a leaflet map with Django.

I asked about how to correct this ([Link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287150/django-geodjango-read-coordinates-in-the-wrong-order)) but got no answer and haven't been able to solve it myself. Therefore, the only thing I can think of is to try with previous versions of GDAL, however, I'm not quite sure how to do it. I followed the next steps to install it:

```
pip3 install gdal
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-gdal
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I tried with 2.x.x versions, but i'm getting some errors wtih every version under 3.

When executing `pip3 install gdal==2.4.4`, first I get the errors `command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with status 1` and `ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal`. Then it uninstalls GDAL 3.0.4 successfully and after a while it reports another status 1:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cjqeh4e7/gdal/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cjqeh4e7/gdal/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_71slwxo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/ecolab/.local/include/python3.8/gdal Check the logs for full command output.
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929 Exception information:
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929 Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929     status = self.run(options, args)
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 421, in run
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929     installed = install_given_reqs(
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 67, in install_given_reqs
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929     requirement.install(
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 820, in install
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929     install_legacy(
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/legacy.py", line 70, in install
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929     runner(
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 271, in runner
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929     call_subprocess(
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929     raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
2020-06-16T11:34:18,929 pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cjqeh4e7/gdal/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cjqeh4e7/gdal/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_71slwxo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/ecolab/.local/include/python3.8/gdal Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is (currently) no GDAL packages for focal (20.04) in the  ubuntugis PPA `https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa`.

The best way might be to build the GDAL 2.2.4 and GEOS 3.8.0 librairies from the sources as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#building-from-source.

You must uninstall the GDAL v3 version if already installed in your OS using `sudo apt-get remove gdal-bin gdal-data libgdal26`

Then you can do the following:

**Install GEOS (bzip2):**

```
cd /tmp/
wget https://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.8.0.tar.bz2
tar xjf geos-3.8.0.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.8.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Install GDAL (gzip):**

```
cd /tmp/
wget https://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.2.4/gdal-2.2.4.tar.gz
tar xzf gdal-2.2.4.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.2.4
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Run ldconfig:**

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: I finally decided to use Leaflet to generate the maps, as well as for the forms in which I needed to collect geospatial information. Anyway, I tried the solution proposed by Benjamin and seems to work well. Thanks for your time, it will probably be useful in future projects if the problems with GDAL +3 persist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install an older version with pip? Something like `pip3 install gdal==2.3.3`?

Comment: I'm getting an error while building wheel when I execute this command in every version previous to 3.0.1 (I had 3.0.4).This version still has this problem. I'm not sure of what's causing the errors.

Comment: If I install the older version, to tell Django to use the older version, do I just have to specify it with GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH or django will recognise it 
automatically?

Comment: Which version do you try to install exactly? Can you add the exact error you get?

Comment: I updated my question with the errors that i'm getting, Thanks

Comment: I've tried to install GDAL on a clean version of ubuntu 20.4 lts.  It seems like the version of gdal, which you want to install with pip, has to be equal with the version of the gdal-bin installed by the `apt-get` command. Something similar is mentioned in the documentation. https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html#install-gdal-ogr. I've tried to install / find an older version of the gdal-bin with `apt-cache policy` but haven't found one.

Comment: Maybe it's easier and better to adapt yourself to the knewest version? Can't you just reorder the data? Can you maybe post an example of how the data is and how it shall be?

Comment: Yeah, that's what i tried at first. I prefer to adapt myself to the newest version as you said. The problem it's explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287150/django-geodjango-read-coordinates-in-the-wrong-order but i got no answer. I have continued with other tasks but i'm close to finish them and soon i'll have to solve this problem

Comment: I don't know exactly what your query returns, but maybe you can use .order_by() (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) to get the data like it should be. Or if order_by doesn't offer the required functionality I would use sorted() (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: I'll give it a try this weekend. This is driving me crazy. Thank you so much for your help and time. Hope this works.

Comment: Did you made any progress?

Comment: Nope. I tried to swap simple Points values (I have a GeometryCollection Field, so it can contain Polygons, Lines,..) in the __init__ of the form, and i know how swap them, it's not a problem but for some reason the changes are not saving. I'm trying to modify the values of the instance with a for loop in kwargs['instance'].my_field but no luck. I can change other values with something like kwargs['instance'].name = "Some name" but can't change the coordinates. I don't know if the map is rendering before everything else and this is why i can't change the positions after that..